# spatstat rbind.hyperframe crashes after update to v1.63

Tags: r, rbind, spatstat

In the last weeks, I had problems with rbind.hyperframe since it crashes with the following error:

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
>   check.names = TRUE, : row names supplied are of the wrong length
>
> 6. stop("row names supplied are of the wrong length")
> 7. (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, fix.empty.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors =
>      default.stringsAsFactors()) { data.row.names <- if (check.rows &&
>      is.null(row.names)) ...
> 8. do.call(data.frame, append(aarg[dfcolumns], list(row.names = row.names, check.rows = check.rows, check.names = check.names,
>      stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)))
> 9. (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors()) { aarg <-
>      list(...) ...
> 10. do.call(hyperframe, append(rslt, list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = rona)))
> 11. rbind.hyperframe(hfs, hf)

I found out that rbind.hyperframe was changed in one of the last updates since v1.60. A section for creating row names was added. If I remove that section, everything works fine again.

```
# rbind.hyperframe of spatstat v1.63-3
function (...) 
{
    argh <- list(...)
    if (length(argh) == 0) 
        return(NULL)
    argh <- lapply(argh, as.hyperframe)
    nargh <- length(argh)
    if (nargh == 1) 
        return(argh[[1L]])
    dfs <- lapply(argh, as.data.frame, discard = FALSE)
    dfall <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
    dfs0 <- lapply(argh, as.data.frame, discard = TRUE, warn = FALSE)
    df0all <- do.call(rbind, dfs0)
    rslt <- list()
    nam <- names(dfall)
    nam0 <- names(df0all)
    for (k in seq_along(nam)) {
        nama <- nam[k]
        if (nama %in% nam0) {
            rslt[[k]] <- dfall[, k]
        }
        else {
            hdata <- lapply(argh, "[", j = nama, drop = FALSE)
            hdata <- lapply(lapply(hdata, as.list), getElement, 
                name = nama)
            hh <- hdata[[1L]]
            for (j in 2:nargh) {
                hh <- append(hh, hdata[[j]])
            }
            rslt[[k]] <- hh
        }
    }
    rona <- sapply(dfs, row.names) # New code
    rona <- make.names(rona, unique = TRUE) # New code
    names(rslt) <- nam
    out <- do.call(hyperframe, append(rslt, list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
        row.names = rona))) # new code
    return(out)
}
```

```
# rbind.hyperframe of spatstat v1.60-1
function (...) 
{
    argh <- list(...)
    if (length(argh) == 0) 
        return(NULL)
    argh <- lapply(argh, as.hyperframe)
    nargh <- length(argh)
    if (nargh == 1) 
        return(argh[[1L]])
    dfs <- lapply(argh, as.data.frame, discard = FALSE)
    dfall <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
    dfs0 <- lapply(argh, as.data.frame, discard = TRUE, warn = FALSE)
    df0all <- do.call(rbind, dfs0)
    rslt <- list()
    nam <- names(dfall)
    nam0 <- names(df0all)
    for (k in seq_along(nam)) {
        nama <- nam[k]
        if (nama %in% nam0) {
            rslt[[k]] <- dfall[, k]
        }
        else {
            hdata <- lapply(argh, "[", j = nama, drop = FALSE)
            hdata <- lapply(lapply(hdata, as.list), getElement, 
                name = nama)
            hh <- hdata[[1L]]
            for (j in 2:nargh) {
                hh <- append(hh, hdata[[j]])
            }
            rslt[[k]] <- hh
        }
    }
    names(rslt) <- nam
    out <- do.call(hyperframe, append(rslt, list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
    return(out)
}
```

Example code, where rbind.hyperframe causes the error

---

EDIT: Removed first example since it was not reproducible. 
Here are two short examples.

```
> library(spatstat)
Lade nötiges Paket: spatstat.data
Lade nötiges Paket: nlme
Lade nötiges Paket: rpart

spatstat 1.63-3       (nickname: ‘Wet paint’) 
For an introduction to spatstat, type ‘beginner’ 

> 
> for (i in 1:3) {
+     df <- data.frame(1,2,3,4,5)
+     list_of <- listof(rnorm(10))
+     
+     hf <- cbind.hyperframe(df, list_of)
+     
+     if (i == 1) {
+         hfs <- hf
+     } else {
+         hfs <- rbind.hyperframe(hfs, hf)
+     }
+ }
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length
> 
> print(hf)
Hyperframe:
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5        V1
X1  1  2  3  4  5 (numeric)
> print(hfs)
Hyperframe:
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5        V1
X1    1  2  3  4  5 (numeric)
X1.1  1  2  3  4  5 (numeric)
> 
> 
> for (i in 1:3) {
+     df <- data.frame(1,2,3,4,5)
+     hf <- as.hyperframe.data.frame(df)
+ 
+     if (i == 1) {
+         hfs <- hf
+     } else {
+         hfs <- rbind.hyperframe(hfs, hf)
+     }
+ }
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length
> 
> print(hf)
Hyperframe:
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4  5
> print(hfs)
Hyperframe:
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
X1    1  2  3  4  5
X1.1  1  2  3  4  5
> 
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] spatstat_1.63-3     rpart_4.1-15        nlme_3.1-144        spatstat.data_1.4-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.3        deldir_0.1-25         Matrix_1.2-18         spatstat.utils_1.17-0 tools_3.6.3          
 [6] mgcv_1.8-31           abind_1.4-5           splines_3.6.3         grid_3.6.3            polyclip_1.10-0      
[11] goftest_1.2-2         lattice_0.20-38       tensor_1.5
```

I tested them on a different computer with an older version of spatstat as well. The new version of cbind.hyperframe changes the row names as well.

------ Another computer without problem -------------

```
> library(spatstat)
Lade nötiges Paket: spatstat.data
Lade nötiges Paket: nlme
Lade nötiges Paket: rpart

spatstat 1.60-1       (nickname: ‘Swinging Sixties’) 
For an introduction to spatstat, type ‘beginner’ 


Note: R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) is more than 9 months old; we strongly recommend upgrading to the latest version
> 
> for (i in 1:3) {
+     df <- data.frame(1,2,3,4,5)
+     list_of <- listof(rnorm(10))
+     
+     hf <- cbind.hyperframe(df, list_of)
+     
+     if (i == 1) {
+         hfs <- hf
+     } else {
+         hfs <- rbind.hyperframe(hfs, hf)
+     }
+ }
> print(hf)
Hyperframe:
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5        V1
1  1  2  3  4  5 (numeric)
> print(hfs)
Hyperframe:
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5        V1
1  1  2  3  4  5 (numeric)
2  1  2  3  4  5 (numeric)
3  1  2  3  4  5 (numeric)
> 
> 
> for (i in 1:3) {
+     df <- data.frame(1,2,3,4,5)
+     hf <- as.hyperframe.data.frame(df)
+ 
+     if (i == 1) {
+         hfs <- hf
+     } else {
+         hfs <- rbind.hyperframe(hfs, hf)
+     }
+ }
> print(hf)
Hyperframe:
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4  5
> print(hfs)
Hyperframe:
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  1  2  3  4  5
3  1  2  3  4  5
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] spatstat_1.60-1     rpart_4.1-15        nlme_3.1-140        spatstat.data_1.4-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.1        deldir_0.1-23         Matrix_1.2-17        
 [4] spatstat.utils_1.13-0 tools_3.6.1           mgcv_1.8-28          
 [7] abind_1.4-5           splines_3.6.1         grid_3.6.1           
[10] polyclip_1.10-0       goftest_1.1-1         lattice_0.20-38      
[13] tensor_1.5
```

Comment: This code contains undefined variables (eg `path_main_folder`) so the example is not reproducible

Comment: Please provide the `.rds` files that were used in this example, or provide another self-contained example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Also please confirm whether the `spatstat` package was loaded, and which version of `R` and `spatstat` was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that this is a bug. It is now fixed in the development version of `spatstat` (version 1.64-0.001 and later).

Bug reports should be posted at the [spatstat package bug reports page](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat/issues)

Comment: I created an issue on GitHub

Comment: This bug fix will soon be published on CRAN as `spatstat 1.64-1`